# "Past" as a Verb

Tags: grammaticality, orthography, parts-of-speech, inflectional-morphology

I have come across a sentence in a financial media website Investopedia, which reads, "Time-barred debt is typically debt that *has past* the statute of limitations and cannot be collected."

My question is if the sentence is grammatically correct. I assume, in the phrase "*has past*", past is used as a verb. Can past be used as a verb, even in informal context?

Comment: It's a misspelling. Should be _passed_. They're pronounced the same, so it might be a transcription error

Comment: **Yes, it is certainly *grammatically* correct;** just speak it aloud and you'll realize this. However, as John has pointed out, it has a spelling mistake. Spelling mistakes are not grammatical errors, just errors in writing. Grammatical errors are heard not seen.

Comment: By collective agreement of writers of present-day English, whenever the 
word /pæst/ represents a noun, adjective, adverb, or preposition, we **always** 
spell it [*past*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/past).
In contrast but also by collective agreement, when the word /pæst/
represents the past tense or the past participle of the verb /pæs/, we
always spell it [*passed*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/passed).
Certainly both ultimately derive from the selfsame verb /pæs/, and indeed
centuries ago these two words were not always clearly
distinguished in writing as nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist